# PHP form to email headers combining 3 variables in the header

Tags: php, email

I have php script that is working fine (almost perfectly) however I have a small issue with the sender details in the email header.
I have the following lines as part of the script

```
$headers =
    "From: \"$fullname0\" <$fromemail>" . $linesep . "Reply-To: \"$fullname0\" <$email>" .  
$linesep . "X-Mailer: chfeedback.php 2.20.2" .
$linesep . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $linesep . CONTENT_TYPE ;

if ($use_envsender && !ini_get('safe_mode')) {
mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, $headers, $envsender );
}
else {
mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, $headers );
}
header( "Location: $thankyouurl" );
exit ;
```

So far, so good, this returns, (in the email header "from") being the contact name  & email address <$email>.

Can the script be modified to include a company name <$fullname> if that is included with the enquiry?
I guess I am looking for sender | company | email address when both company name & contact name are included + email address.
Does this make sense or & I just dreaming?
Cheerz

Comment: It may well be easier to use a proper full mailer wrapper such as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)  which makes the whole process soooo much better and far less fiddly.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Does "sender | company | email address" mean sender *or* company *or* email address? Or does it mean sender, company, and email address, all separated with the pipe symbol? Please provide a specific example of your intended output, and describe where "sender" and "company name" are coming from.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is appreciated, The scenario is as follows, I expect to receive responses from A) a contact name & email address or B) a company, a contact name & an email address...  at the moment I can pick up the contact name & the email address but I would like to pick up the company name as well  (if & when applicable) if possible. Cheerz

Comment: My apologies to any that have given this more than a few seconds of thought, perhaps I should have done so myself before asking the question.  I was looking for some way of seperating spam from genuine email under specific circumstances.  I can probably live with a "contact name" + "(email address)" in brackets as the corespondent in my email (thunderbird), the |'s above were probably a poor choice of mine but I was just using them to provide some seperation of the ideal result.  I think that I will tuck my head under my tail & rethink this